# How to pull data from sas server to hdfs using Java?

Tags: java, hadoop, sas, bigdata

I am suppose to pull the data from sas Server and put it into the HDFS.I want to use java code for the same any Idea please.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest mechanism is going to be to install the Hadoop client libraries and then upload your SAS files onto HDFS via the client commands:  `hadoop fs -put <filename> </hdfs/path/filename>`

If you don't want to use the client commands, you can always write your own java application to perform the upload from the SAS server to HDFS.  An untested piece of example code that transfers a file using the fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile interface:

```
package org.mycompany;
import java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;

public class HDFSTransfer {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            UserGroupInformation ugi
                = UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("myuser");

            ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {

                public Void run() throws Exception {

                    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
                    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://10.20.30.40:8020/user/myuser");
                    conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "myuser");

                    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

                    fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("/local/file/test"), new Path("/user/myuser/test"));

                    FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path("/user/myuser"));
                    for(int i=0;i<status.length;i++){
                        System.out.println(status[i].getPath());
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jam for your response..In this code you are copying the files from the local if I am not wrong,So i guess according to you first get the data from sas server to local then go for this code?Correct me i am wrong.....

Comment: That's correct ... based on the question, I thought you wanted to transfer SAS data from the SAS server to the Hadoop environment using a java program.  Another way of doing it would be to open the datasets in SAS, and using the SAS Hadoop connector (which connects to Hiveserver2), you can load the data into hive tables on Hadoop.

Comment: through the java I have already done that,But same thing retrieving sas data to the local and pull that into hdfs...now the second approach you suggested is making good sound ...i will try for that.....and really thanks for the help Jam.......